# How to find the closet value to input provided from list

Tags: python

I am stuck at this point. Need to find the closet value near to my input

```
mylist = [1,8,4,88,100]

inp=5
```

**My output:**
`4`

I now using for loop to but need some more efficient way to handle

As the`inp = 5 ->`The nearest value to my input is `4.` So my output is `4`

Comment: is the list sorted?

Answer (score 1):

Get the absolute diff, from there you will get the nearest value. Then get the element from the index. `enumerate` gives you the index.

```py
mylist = [1,8,4,88,100]

inp=5

closest_val = mylist[min([abs(i-inp), index] for index, i in enumerate(mylist))[-1]] #4
```

Comment: We had the exactly same thought, but implemented in slightly different ways. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using a comprehension:

```
numbers = [1, 8, 4, 88, 100]
n = 5
distances = [abs(n - e) for e in numbers]
closest = numbers[distances.index(min(distances))]
```

Which leaves `closest` set with:

```
4
```

One thing to have in mind is that this method will give you the first closest number according to the order the numbers appear in the list. In other words, if you have two numbers with the same distance, the first one in the list is presented.

Something like this:

```py
>>> numbers = [1, 8, 6, 4, 88, 100]
>>> n = 5
>>> distances = [abs(n - e) for e in numbers]
>>> closest = numbers[distances.index(min(distances))]
>>> closest
6

>>> numbers = [1, 8, 4, 6, 88, 100]
>>> n = 5
>>> distances = [abs(n - e) for e in numbers]
>>> closest = numbers[distances.index(min(distances))]
>>> closest
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities arise.

1. If the list is sorted, then you can use binary search to reach  to the closest values. You can then compare values to the left and right and the one with minimum difference is your desired result.
2. If the list is not sorted, then you'll have to scan the entire list and keep track of the one that gives you least result. Then the one that gives you minimum absolute difference is your answer.